# Pass imploded string as a couple of parameters

Tags: php

I want to do something like that:

`call_user_func(array('Class', 'Method'), implode(", ", $array));`

Is it possible? The imploded string contains a couple of expressions. In this shape however, if $array contains 2 elements, I get an error that Class::method() needs 2 parameters, not 1.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You want [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) instead.

```
call_user_func_array(array('Class', 'Method'), $array);
```